# populating the views with images from array

Tags: objective-c, ios

I got 10 views on my main view, each view has a image, and i got my images in an array, how can i populate my views with images from my array. Any pointers please.
Thanks

Comment: "Any pointers please." -- here you are: `(const char *)0x3f451290`

Comment: yes, on the views there are button and i  can use these images as background to that buttons, but how to get each element from array to point to that particular view.

Answer (score 0):

addSubView of UIImageView to the main view and add the images to the ImageView like this

```
[imageView setImage:(UIImage*)[array objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Comment: but there are 10 views and each view has a image and an array of 10 images, how can i do that

Comment: use a button to change the image from the array, use int variable "counter" and add image to ImageView
There [array objectAtIndex:0] specifies image1 [array objectAtIndex:1] specifies image 2 and go on similarly

Answer (score 0):

what about putting your views into a corresponding array and looping through like this

```
    for (in i = 0; i < [viewArray count]; i++) {

        UIImageView *temp = [viewArray objectAtIndex:i];
        temp.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
    }
```

It's hard to say really, it depends on how you wanted to manage you views and getting them into an array. This method does rely on keeping track of views in array positions.

Comment: my views are not in array, i tagged them with unique number and in for loop i am using the tags , i want each view to have a image from my array

Comment: ok you need to post up your code really as it's damn near impossible to tell what you want to do. It's a design choice once you get past setting the image part of the imageView etc and its hard to tell what you want wioth no context

Answer (score 0):

Make all **UIButtons to UIButtonTypeCustom** in all views and set Tag from 0 to all views

Now use this

```
for(int i = 0; i<[menuList count]; i++)
{
  UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:i];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[menuList objectAtIndex:i]];
    //NSLog(@"Hopefull MainImage: %@", url);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //NSLog(@"data:%@", data);
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    //NSLog(@"img %@", img);

    UIImage *stretchableButtonImage = [img stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
  for(int j = 0; i<[[view subViews]count]; i++)
  {
    [[view  objectAtIndex:j] setBackgroundImage:stretchableButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }

}
```

Comment: on the views i got 2 buttons with tages 1 and 2, i want to show the image from array to all the buttons with tag 1 and looping through array of images.

Comment: as i said, the buttons are not in array, they are with tags, you can see my code in pastebin, the link i sent.

Comment: now check my edited answer as i have assumed menulist as your imagearray with urls

Comment: yes use these method instead of for (int tag =110; tag<123; tag++)

Comment: for j loop, it gives me view as error, not initilised i think

Comment: have u set tag 0 to 9 to all views containing 2 buttons

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12706/discussion-between-safecase-and-sj-reddy)